# New to c# and having issues with case statements for a simple menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm getting an error of CS8070  Control cannot fall out of switch from final case label ('case 1:'). No information from MS about the error code and can't seem to see why it is complaining.

I plan of adding more to the code but don't want to get too far before having to change a lot.

```
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Please select one option below:");
            Console.WriteLine("1) BMI calculator");
            Console.WriteLine("2 ) Membership rates calculator");
            selection = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch (selection)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Write("Please enter your weight in kilograms:");
                    weight = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//gets users weight
                    Console.Write("Please enter your height in meters:");
                    height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//gets users height
                    bmi = (weight / (height * height));//does caculation. 
                    if (bmi < 18.5)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is " + bmi + " and you are underweight");
                    }
                    if ((bmi > 18.6) || (bmi < 25))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is " + bmi + " and you are of normal weight");
                    }
                    if ((bmi > 25.1) || (bmi < 30))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is " + bmi + " and you are overweight");
                    }
                    if (bmi > 30.1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is " + bmi + " and you are obese");
                    }
            }
```

Comment: The end of your case statement is reachable, and that's the final case in the switch. You need a `break` statement.

Comment: Legend. Thanks for the swift response.

Comment: FYI, if you use `else if`, then you don't need to repeat the previous test - if the first test catches `bmi < 18.5` then the next else-if can just test for `bmi < 25`. This also prevents values between 18.5 and 18.6 from falling between the cracks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every case statement containing code should be closed with break;

```
            Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Please select one option below:");
        Console.WriteLine("1) BMI calculator");
        Console.WriteLine("2 ) Membership rates calculator");
        selection = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (selection)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.Write("Please enter your weight in kilograms:");
                weight = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//gets users weight
                Console.Write("Please enter your height in meters:");
                height = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());//gets users height
                bmi = (weight / (height * height));//does caculation. 
                if (bmi < 18.5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is " + bmi + " and you are underweight");
                }
                if ((bmi > 18.6) || (bmi < 25))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is " + bmi + " and you are of normal weight");
                }
                if ((bmi > 25.1) || (bmi < 30))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is " + bmi + " and you are overweight");
                }
                if (bmi > 30.1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Your BMI is " + bmi + " and you are obese");
                }
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Of the switch statement, C# follows the C convention so that you need a 'break;' at the end of every case.

Comment: Isn't it legal in C to fall through to the next case, which is explicitly forbidden in C#?

Comment: Yes, you're right. However, C# only avoids 'falling through cases', not the 'break'.